# Successfully connected using SqlOledb but Unable to Connect Using sqlClient

Tags: sqlclient

Hy friends,

I have struggled with this problem all day long. I have asp .net 4.0 web application running on iis 7. It running well when not performing connectivity on database.

I am using sqlserver 2005. when i connect to server using the SqlClient it produces error as follows:

```
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.)
```

but when i use sqloledb to connect to my remote database,then successfully connected. I would appreciate if anyone could give me some solution regarding to my problem.

Thank you.

Comment: What connection strings are you using for SqlOledb and SqlClient?